# How we can handle dynamic web service in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, web-services, dynamic

I am learning some tricky development in iPhone and during my experiments I found out that usually we used localized web-service in which all parameter are fixed(Keyword). If my web service will change some fields in the response than how can we handle in iPhone. Please help me. If Anybody have any good idea.

For Example,
Webservice Response1:

```
    [    {
      "Number":"A12 hrb",
      "List":[
         {
            "Type":"Works",
            "Display":{
               "dop":45,
               "dopper":56
            },
            "OAST":"10-01-2012",
            "OAET":"07-04-2012",
            "Cause":"define",
            "Impact":"Queue",
            "Description":"Take a Break.",
            "LName":"Lunetten To Lunetten",
            "Number":"A12 hrb",
         }
      ]    },   ]
```

Webservice Response2:

```
[    {
      "Number":"A12 hrb",
      "Number2":"A13 brs",
      "List":[
         {
            "Type":"Works",
            "Display":{
               "dop":45,
               "dopper":56
               "picker":90  
            },
            "OAST":"10-01-2012",
            "MAET":"07-04-2012", 
            "OAET":"07-04-2012",
            "Cause":"define",
            "Impact":"Queue",
            "Description":"Take a Break.",
            "LName":"Lunetten To Lunetten",
            "Number":"A12 hrb",
         }
      ]    },   ]
```

Comment: If the question is how to parse JSON, take a look at JSONKit.

Comment: do you have control over webservice? or is it a third-party webservice?

Comment: It's third party web service.But its not matter whose web-service.The matter is web service response keep changing..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

1. Parse the response.If response is JSON then definitely  you will get a dictionary just keep a reference of it.
2. you can get all the keys in dictionary by calling following method

   - (NSArray *)allKeys
3. now enumerate above array and access the values respective to each key and do whatever you want

But you should know the meaning/purpose of dynamic keys. If you don't no meaning/purpose of keys these steps may not help you... best of luck.

Comment: Thanks For Reply,Using [(NSArray *)allKeys] method we can get only main key. Like, If I use this method for my web service as mentioned in above than we can get only "Number","List". Where for inner keys we have to make another dictionary and do all these process again. Event we don't know if there is any sub dictionary or not. It might get complex for nested json web service.It's not proper solution.I have tried it earlier.

Comment: Ya you are correct it is not proper, but you can write a recursive method that will do all this thing. I don't think there is any ready made api for this, you need to handle all these manually. I can suggest only to write one method that can handle all possibilities dictionary array any thing ..... best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible to parse it completely. Atleast you should know which keys are going to be there. e.g. response has Number, Number2 & List as keys. It's ok if some responses do not contain one/some of the keys.

On the other hand, if knowing all the keys in advance is at all not possible, then webservice should have mechanism to convey the keys used in response.

> e.g.
>
> ```
>  [    {
>       "dynamic_keys": "Number2",
>       "Number":"A12 hrb",
>       "Number2":"A13 brs",
>       "List":[
>          {
>             "Type":"Works",
>             "Display":{
>                "dop":45,
>                "dopper":56
>                "picker":90
>
>             },
>             "OAST":"10-01-2012",
>             "MAET":"07-04-2012", 
>             "OAET":"07-04-2012",
>             "Cause":"define",
>             "Impact":"Queue",
>             "Description":"Take a Break.",
>             "LName":"Lunetten To Lunetten",
>             "Number":"A12 hrb",
>          }
>       ]    },   ]
> ```

You can read the value of "dynamic_keys" and then using that value you can read value of actual dynamic key.

edit: as mentioned by ssteinberg you can use some framework like JSONKit to parse actual JSON.
See this as well: [How to parse JSON having dynamic key node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414099/how-to-parse-json-having-dynamic-key-node/9414853#9414853)

Answer (score 0):

> For this type of case you can get the dictionary and in dictionary you
>   can get the value of which tag you want means you just need root node
>   and store root node all the data in dictionary and handle that
>   dictionary for the further use..